# Есть ли способ указать несколько возможных типов для аргумента функции в Kotlin?

Tags: функции, kotlin, тестирование

Я пишу тест для API метода, который может принимать несколько типов данных, но, понятное дело, не все. Мне бы хотелось найти возможность передавать в функцию один из возможных типов в духе `String or Int`.

Знаю возможные варианты решения, но мне они не нравятся:

1. Использовать тип `Any` - небезопасно и как-то не очень вообще.
2. Повторно объявить функцию, где будет указан уже другой тип аргумента - невозможно, некоторые методы принимают множество подобных аргументов. Я так понимаю, что так придется делать для каждой комбинации разных типов?

Пример минимально воспроизводимого кода:

```
fun main() {
    
    fun myRequestMethod(
        firstParam: Any, //actualy can be ONLY String or Int
        secondParam: Any, //actualy can be ONLY String or Int
        thirdParam: Any //actualy can be ONLY String or Int
    ) {
        //do api-request
        println("$firstParam, $secondParam, $thirdParam")
    }
    
    myRequestMethod(1, 2, 3) //acceptible with Any type
    myRequestMethod("1", 2, "3") //acceptible with Any type
    myRequestMethod(mapOf("1" to 1), listOf(2, 2, 2), "3") //NOT acceptible with Any type
    myRequestMethod(1, listOf(1, 2, 3), mapOf("1" to 1)) //NOT acceptible with Any type
}
```

Может есть какое-то решение, которое я не смог найти? Спасибо!

Comment: Сделайте по функции для каждого набора аргументов. *"Повторно объявить функцию, где будет указан уже другой тип аргумента - невозможно,"* - ¿с чего бы это?

Comment: @user7860670 там может быть множество наборов таких параметров, получается, что должна быть функция под каждый из возможных наборов, если я правильно понимаю.

Comment: Приведите какой-то более приближенный к реальности пример. На примере из вопроса вполне нормально будет и Any. В принципе, можно какой-то (дата)класс создать для передачи набора параметров, и его указать его как аргумент функции.

Comment: @insolor изменил пример кода в описании

Comment: А какие операции вы дальше будете делать с firstParam, secondParam и thirdParam? Сделайте интерфейс или sealed-класс с нужными методами, исходя из того, как вы будете использовать эти параметры.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Именно так, как вы хотите, сделать нельзя, но можно сделать `sealed`-класс с двумя реализациями:

```kotlin
sealed class Param

class IntParam(val value: Int) : Param()

class StringParam(val value: String) : Param()
```

И пару экстеншенов для удобства:

```kotlin
val Int.param get() = IntParam(this)

val String.param get() = StringParam(this)
```

Вместо `Any` теперь можно использовать `Param`, а вызывать метод можно будет следующим образом:

```kotlin
myRequestMethod(1.param, 2.param, 3.param)
myRequestMethod("1".param, 2.param, "3".param)
```

Конечно, это не совсем то, что вы хотели, но я попытался максимально приблизить к тому, что требовалось.

Кроме этого, в `sealed`-класс можно добавить какой-нибудь абстрактный метод, в зависимости от того, как вы дальше планируете работать с этими параметрами в коде.